# iOS navigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

this is probably quite simple.. but I don't know what's the best practice here.

i have a tabbarcontroller with 4 tabs, 3 of them should be a UINavigationController, the other one should also have the UINavigationBar to it but should not be a nav controller itself.
Now i want to give the UINavigationBar a tint color and an action button. I'd like to do this in the interface builder.
The navBar should always be the same one and i only want to create it once.

But where exactly would i do it? Would i create a .xib file with only the UINavigationBar in it and somehow link to that?

I'm very confused here, most tutorials only discuss the navBar for ONE navController but in my case i need the same bar for different ViewControllers..

Comment: Why do you want different view controllers for one nav bar? You said you wanted it only in one of the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavBar comes with the navigationController or can come seperate. It is a subclass of UIView.

You cannot simply share your navBar with all controllers and the non-navigationController. I mean one instance of a navbar. You cannot even set the navbar for a navigationController. It is only readable.

In my understanding you are trying to make the navbar look the same in every controller, am I right?
So you can for instance subclass a UINavigationController and set it up as you want in the `init` method and init this subclass to add it to the view.

*But what about the non-UINavigationController navBar?*
Well, that's easy: Simply add your subclassed navigationController to that tab. You don't have to use it as NavController. You simply can add views to his view as to a standard ViewController.

Comment: thanks! i subclassed uinavigationcontroller and used the subclass for the navcontrollers in my appdelegate. it works well programatically (i set the tint color to red to try it), but is there any way to customize the navbar in IB? just wondering..

Comment: No there isn't. That's why we all have to do our jobs (programming). :-)